# Jersey RestFul : how to prevent One Session per User

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey

**I am using RestFul Web Services .**

My question is that , why the Framework is creating More than One session for each Service .

**This is my service class**

```
@Path("/balances")
public class HelloService {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest req1;
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest req2;


    public String sayPlainTextHello(String account) {
    HttpSession session1 = req1.getSession(true);
    HttpSession session2 = req2.getSession(true);
    System.out.println("First Session id" + session1.getId());
    System.out.println("second Session id" + session2.getId());
    return "";
    }

}
```

**The Output of the above is**

```
First Session id8D8DEF5AC8D1DEDC59F20AE875EE0B70
second Session id8D8DEF5AC8D1DEDC59F20AE875EE0B70
```

**This is my another Service class**

```
@Path("/hais")
public class HaiService {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest req3;
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest req4;
    public String sayPlainTextHello(String account) {
    HttpSession session3 = req3.getSession(true);
        HttpSession session4 = req4.getSession(true);
        System.out.println("For haiiiiiiiiiiis First session id" + session3.getId());
        System.out.println("For haiiiiiiiiiiis  Second session id" + session4.getId());
        return "Testing the hai Service";
    }

}
```

**The Output of the above is**

```
For haiiiiiiiiiiis First session id6DC315D6B833BC16B3EE13C5810B2810
For haiiiiiiiiiiis  Second session id6DC315D6B833BC16B3EE13C5810B2810
```

**Both these service classes are called from with  in a Single Jersey client**

**The client program is**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {


            WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("http://localhost:8080/Tes/ajax/balances/");

            WebResource webResource2 = client
            .resource("http://localhost:8080/Tes/ajax/hais/");
```

**As you can observe , its creating different session id for every service class**

And if i mention false during session creation in the second service class , its throeing Null Pointer Exception with session.getId();

```
HttpSession session1 = req1.getSession(false);  
HttpSession session2 = req2.getSession(false);
```

**or**

```
HttpSession session1 = req1.getSession();  
HttpSession session2 = req2.getSession();
```

Comment: REST is meant to be stateless (ie no information stored in a server session). Have you looked at http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e483 ?